# Using pcolor in matlab loops

Tags: matlab

I have some data points with coordinates lat, lon and value Z ( millions of data points). Each coordinate point represent the center of a grid with size of 0.0005.
   I want to plot them with the color represent the value Z. However, my data is not grid data, they are scatter data points.I know another function "geoshow" also can make similar map, but for grid data. There is out of memory when I convert scatter data to grid data using matlab. So I have achieved this using pcolor. The code below:

```
clc
clear all
data = load('data.txt');% This data.txt file is large, about 100M and each line with lat, lon and value Z 
X = data(:,1); % Lat
Y = data(:,2); %Lon
Z = data(:,3); % Value Z
grid_dx=0.0005;
grid_dy=0.0005;
xl=X-grid_dx/2;
xr=X+grid_dx/2;
yu=Y+grid_dy/2;
yd=Y-grid_dy/2;
for i1=1:length(x)
xx=[xl(i1),xr(i1);xl(i1),xr(i1)];
yy=[yd(i1),yd(i1);yu(i1),yu(i1)];
zz=repmat(z(i1),2,2);
pcolor(xx,yy,zz)
colormap('jet')
end
```

For small data set , it works well. However, it will spend too much time for larger data set. 
    Is it possible to plot the scatter data  much faster without gridding? Any function pcolor , geoshow or something else will be ok.
 Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scatter` function to plot `(x,y)` points with z-based colors without performing an interpolation.

```
lat = sort(10*rand(100,1));  % sorting is optional, just to give a 
lon = sort(10*rand(100,1));  % gradient in the coloring
z = sort(rand(100,1));

scatter(lat, lon, [] , z, 'fill');
```

This code produces

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tryed scatter already. The map it produced is not what I what. I have no authorize to post picture here.The map i wanted is  like the first map at this URL http://jisao.washington.edu/computer_helps/MATLAB_graphics.html#item0   But using scatter data.